# How to remove_action which is call in class

Tags: php, wordpress

```
class Zopim {
private static $_instance = NULL;
private function __construct()
{
    spl_autoload_register( array( &$this, 'autoload' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_footer', array( 'Zopim_Widget', 'zopimme' ) );
    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( &$this, 'load_textdomain' ) );
}
}
```

How i use remove_action to remove below action

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', array( 'Zopim_Widget', 'zopimme' ) );
```

from function.php

Answer (score 0):

You can call `remove_action` on `wp_footer`:

```
remove_action( 'wp_footer', array( 'Zopim', 'zopimme' ) );
```

Depending on when that class is actually called, you may need to pass a priority to tell WordPress to do your `remove_action` a touch later. Because the class doesn't pass a priority to `add_action`, it will be called with a default priority of 10. If you set a higher priority, your call will happen later:

```
remove_action( 'wp_footer', array( 'Zopim', 'zopimme' ), 11 );
```

Comment: Its not working. Because zopimme is not the function of "Zopim" Class. Function zopimme  is  place in Zopim_Widget class